# What kind of KeyInfo does Microsoft ADFS expect to get?

Tags: authentication, saml, adfs, keycloak, xml-signature

Does anybody know what type of `<KeyInfo>` does ADFS expect to find in  field of a `SAMLRequest` message?

There are [several options to choose from](http://coheigea.blogspot.co.il/2013/03/signature-and-encryption-key.html). I'm using [Keycloak SAML library](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/server_admin/topics/clients/client-saml.html), which knows to send this field in `<KeyValue>` format only (which contains modulus & exponent of the RSA public key). Can ADFS digest this?

```
<ds:KeyInfo>
    <ds:KeyValue>
        <ds:RSAKeyValue>
            <ds:Modulus>tfJ29N0G1...</ds:Modulus> 
            <ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
        </ds:RSAKeyValue>
    </ds:KeyValue>
</ds:KeyInfo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question - apparently, the `<KeyInfo>` format doesn't matter.
I got keycloak working with ADFS, while using `<KeyValue>` format only.
As I was [told on keycloak-user](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-April/010508.html) mailing list, "*ADFS should be able to determine the correct certificate for signature validation itself by iterating all
available certificates.*"